# DAX if conditions and vloopup

Tags: powerbi, dax

[image]

Hi everyone,
I got a table for the samples qty received grouped by Shops and grouped by month
I would like to know how to return the sample qty of previous month by different shops
thanks a lot

I added a column "previous month" and use CALCULATE function but it didnt works.

Answer (score 0):

MEASURES AS FOLLOW:

```
sample qty measure = sum('table'[sample qty])
sample qty last month = calculate([sample qty measure],'table'[month]=selectedvalue('table'[month])-1)
samlpe qty by month by shop last month = calculate([sample qty last month],ALLEXCEPT('table','table'[shop],'table'[month]))
samlpe qty by month by shop current month = calculate([sample qty measure],ALLEXCEPT('table','table'[shop],'table'[month]))
```

> *samlpe qty by month by shop last month* is what you want. can check with *samlpe qty by month by shop current month*

result as image below:

[image]